# error: ‘<methodname>’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I recently facing an issue with my cpp code. I'm not a cpp developer and this issue seems to be bit confusing. The code is as flows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "libarff/arff_parser.h"
#include "libarff/arff_data.h"

using namespace std;

int second_loop(int i, ArffData* dataset, float smallestDistance){

    int smallestDistanceClass;

    for(int j = 0; j < dataset->num_instances(); j++) // target each other instance
        {
            if(i == j) 
                continue;

            float distance = third_loop(i, j, dataset);

            distance = sqrt(distance);

            if(distance < smallestDistance) // select the closest one
            {
                smallestDistance = distance;
                smallestDistanceClass = dataset->get_instance(j)->get(dataset->num_attributes() - 1)->operator int32();
            }
        }

    return smallestDistanceClass;

}

float third_loop(int i, int j, ArffData* dataset){

    float distance = 0;

    for(int k = 0; k < dataset->num_attributes() - 1; k++) // compute the distance between the two instances
    {
        float diff = dataset->get_instance(i)->get(k)->operator float() - dataset->get_instance(j)->get(k)->operator float();
        distance += diff * diff;
    }

    return distance;
}

int* KNN(ArffData* dataset)
{
    int* predictions = (int*)malloc(dataset->num_instances() * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < dataset->num_instances(); i++) // for each instance in the dataset
    {
        float smallestDistance = FLT_MAX;
        int smallestDistanceClass = second_loop(i, dataset, smallestDistance);

        predictions[i] = smallestDistanceClass;
    }

    return predictions;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        cout << "Usage: ./main datasets/datasetFile.arff" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    ArffParser parser(argv[1]);
    ArffData *dataset = parser.parse();
    struct timespec start, end;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);

    int* predictions = KNN(dataset);
 }
```

The error getting thrown is as follows.

```
main_new.cpp: In function ‘int second_loop(int, ArffData*, float)’:
main_new.cpp:21:54: error: ‘third_loop’ was not declared in this scope
             float distance = third_loop(i, j, dataset);
                                                      ^
```

Can anyone help me out with this error. The third_loop syntax seems to be right and still this error comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with third loop. In `second_loop()`, you access the function `third_loop()` even though the compiler hasn't seen it yet here:

```
float distance = third_loop(i, j, dataset);
```

The optimal solution would be forward declare the function in the beginning of the file, like this:

```
float third_loop(int, int, ArffData*);
```

This way, when `second_loop()` accesses `third_loop()`, it will be able to do so without error. As advice, I recommend doing this for *all* your functions, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "libarff/arff_parser.h"
#include "libarff/arff_data.h"

using namespace std;
//Forward declarations:
int second_loop(int, ArffData*, float);
float distance = third_loop(i, j, dataset);
int* KNN(ArffData*);
//End of Forward Declarations
//Rest of code...
```

Comment: Thanks Arnav. I'm still learning the basics. That really helps. So in CPP, the compiler should be warned before the method is being called. Got it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

A function must be declared before it can be used. You didn't declare `third_loop` before you used it inside `second_loop`. You did declare `third_loop` but only after the definition of `second_loop`. That is not sufficient.

To fix the program, declare `third_loop` before you use it.